# Rails scaffolding pluralisation is incorrect for "cafe"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a `cafe` and a `cave` controller.

When I try to create my `cafe` using rails scaffolding, via the command

> rails g scaffold cafe name:string

It is deriving the plural form of "cafe" as "caves", which means I can't make my `caves` controller since the name is already used.

How can I make rails use the correct pluralisation?

Comment: I am curious about your application where you have two resources - cafes and caves :)

Comment: Hi salil, actually i have only cafes not caves. but as a learner i wanted to know what if i have to create caves

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create your own inflections.

Add this to your `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
        inflect.plural "cafe", "cafes"
    end
```

*(Restart your server after making this  change. This is not required for the scaffolding command itself but it will be required when you want to actually view/use the code)*

Now when you run `rails g scaffold cafe` you'll get:

```
...
app/views/cafes
      create      app/views/cafes/index.html.erb
      create      app/views/cafes/edit.html.erb
      create      app/views/cafes/show.html.erb
      create      app/views/cafes/new.html.erb
      create      app/views/cafes/_form.html.erb
etc
```

This may help you: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-inflections

Comment: HI soup

thank you very much.

and i also got to know about,
"config/initializers/inflections.rb" there it
contains the comment with code that we may want to use

Comment: +1 for using ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections instead of ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:some_language), which I was using and was preventing me from getting the right result!