# How to customize the singularization of class name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am working on Rails 4.1.0. And i have generated leaves_controller and Leave model  in my application.

But the application generated routes for leaves as like new_leafe, edit_leaf etc.

Actually I want the singularize string of Leave as Leave only, like new_leave_path, edit_leave_path.

If any idea to singularize class name in Rails, please share.

Comment: What you have in the `routes.rb` file? `resources :leaves` or `resource :leave`?

Comment: It is  resources :leaves in my routes.rb

Comment: Can you post your `rake routes output`?

Comment: Try giving `resource :leave`

Comment: Thanks Pavan, It works. But actually, as per my knowledge in routes.rb it's expected to add resource name in plural form. But is it ok if we add singular format of resource name as you suggested?

Comment: Its because of inflections: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861635/rails-scaffolding-pluralisation-is-incorrect-for-cafe 

this question asked already

Comment: Yes! It is totally suggested,if you want `singular_routes`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's only the routes you wish to change, you *could* use the [`as:`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) option:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :leaves, as: "leave"
```

--

Alternatively, if you'd like to set the term within Rails, you may wish to use an `Inflector` like this:

[How do I override rails naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185035/how-do-i-override-rails-naming-conventions)

```
#config/initializers/inflectors.rb
# Add new inflection rules using the following format 
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'leave', 'leaves'
end
```